# Possible causes for poor traction and handling

Tags: honda, prelude, handling

I have a 2001 Honda Prelude SH with about 180,000 miles on it.

For the past 12-18 months, I've noticed consistent strange behavior:

- Very prone to skidding when braking on uneven roads.
- Much earlier loss of traction when cornering.
- When I hit slightly rough patches of road, especially when braking or cornering, it kind of feels like the car "skips" a little. I can't explain it, but e.g if I'm making a turn on a highway and hit a seam in the road, I get the sensation of bouncing to the outside slightly (it doesn't feel like understeering, it feels... weird and slightly out of control).
- Very prone to laying tire when getting started or upshifting at slow speeds (< 20 mph). (Highly unusual for this car)
- I *think* I feel smaller bumps in the road a bit more, especially regular ridges from the way the roads are constructed. But I can't tell if this is in my head or not. Also I moved about 2 years ago and regularly drive on a different set of highways now, so it could just be that the roads here are particularly uneven.
- My steering wheel is about 3-4 degrees right to keep the car straight. It's stable here, it doesn't pull. I don't know if this indicates a problem though.

The behaviors have slowly been getting worse.

Now, I don't keep the car in the greatest shape mostly because I do a lot of city driving and the roads around here are pretty rough, so I can't usually justify it.

But it's starting to become a problem. I'm going to take it to a shop. But I don't want to spend money going down the wrong path. So my question is: **What are the most likely causes of this that I can check out first?**

From my research, I have at least a partial list, although I'm not sure which matches the symptoms the closest, or what I'm missing. So far I've got:

- Damaged suspension linkage components (after writing this [I discovered](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/possible-causes-for-poor-traction-and-handling#comment43729_27355) a slightly bent control arm in the front left, which is also throwing out the alignment).
- Alignment (it's been a while, and the car's been on a lot of rough roads)
- Worn shocks (all the suspension components are still the originals w/ 180k miles)
- Tire wear (but I did get a brand new set of tires about a year ago and I don't remember it helping much; right now I have three of those plus one random used one)
- [Damaged or worn out sway bar](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/possible-causes-for-poor-traction-and-handling#comment43809_27355) (I'll have to take it apart to check).
- [ATTS malfunction](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/possible-causes-for-poor-traction-and-handling#comment43819_27355) (it would have to be something the computer isn't detecting, I'm not seeing any errors).
- [Engine / gearbox mount failure](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/possible-causes-for-poor-traction-and-handling#comment43904_27355), causing weight shifts and unpredictable behavior.
- Something with the brakes? Like pressure or alignment problems? Can that happen? (My pads / rotors / calipers are in good shape) ABS problems? (the skidding isn't only when braking though, and I have no error indicators, and it doesn't feel like ABS issues anyways)
- Wheel balance (shouldn't be causing the problems I'm seeing)

It's also possible that there's more than one thing going on at the same time contributing to this.

Extra random info in responses to comments:

- Does not make noise over bumps.
- No brake wobble.
- "Skipping" generally settles immediately upon returning to a better road surface.
- No problems with tight U-turns.
- While steering wheel is off by a couple degrees, the steering itself is still super tight, no problems there.
- There are no error codes, and no dash warning indicators are lit.
- Still has the original sway bar (all suspension and linkage components are still the originals except the front left half shaft, which is about 2 and a half years old).

Comment: Sounds like something isn't keeping the front tires on the road. How's the suspension? Does it make noise going over bumps? When you say the car bounces does it settle immediately or does it continue for a few seconds? Does braking feel normal? Are the brakes locking the tires up? How's the tire tread? Is it wearing uneven? Is it low? Is the steering loose? if you center the wheel with the car running how much can you move the steering wheel side to side without the tires moving?

Comment: @Ben It doesn't make noises over bumps (it used to; there was something wrong with one of the joints on the front left axle, but I had the half axle replaced and it's been fine since). When it "skips" it settles immediately. The braking feels normal at high speed, no wobble, but the front left is noisy (quiet scratchy sound, not a squeak, but pads aren't low and rotors aren't thin). At low speeds it's weird; the wheels lock more readily... I'll play around and have clearer observations about the brakes tomorrow. The tread wear is even on all four wheels (I checked this afternoon).

Comment: Steering is super tight, no problems there. Also re: the brakes at low speeds; the wheels lock and the abs doesn't kick in when it skids (I don't have to slam the brakes to make it skid)... I am having a hard time explaining it. And re: the "skips", while it settles immediately, I still understeer more easily even on smooth roads, the bouncing is a second problem on top of that.

Comment: I think you really need to get new shocks/struts. You are losing traction because they aren't keeping your suspension on the road.

Comment: Does the Honda Prelude have its original sway bar / anti-roll bar?

Comment: @mr_tuner Yes, it does.

Comment: We discovered the front left control arm is bent and the camber on both sides is off by about 3 degrees. I think I'm onto something here. Once I get that and the alignment taken care of well see if it feels normal again.

Comment: I think it wouldn't hurt to examine the sway bar. The sway bar can cause many traction and handling issues if there are imperfections with it.

Comment: If the prelude is an SH, it might have ATTS, which is basically an active differential directing additional (up to 20% if I remember correctly) torque to the outside wheel when turning. You can imagine what kind of problems it could cause if the system malfunctioned or the wheel centering was off. Something to consider... But it's almost certain you need new shocks/struts as well.

Comment: @lathejockey81 It has atts. I considered that first actually. I ruled it out because it's not throwing any error codes, but I might be putting too much faith in the computers ability to see atts problems. So I'll add it back to my list. The only way I'll really be able to find that one is to have a dealer inspect it. I'm going to save that as a last resort since it'll probably be the most $$$ repairs. Somehow it feels like it's a problem with some passive system though, although I can't explain why, just a gut feeling. I'm banking on the bent control arm first.

Comment: Don't discount the failure of an engine / gearbox mount.  This can make a car very unpredictable as the weight of the engine shifts about in the engine bay.

Comment: @JasonC make sure a failure in the ATTS system usually throws a code or not with the prelude community. not all failures throw codes well and some things are more prone to fail in the secretive way.

Comment: @JasonC wtf bent control arm? is that mentioned in the q?

Comment: @Zero It's mentioned. It's in the list of things that might cause it. I didn't find out the arm was bent until late in this process after I wrote this and after your answer. I'm pretty sure it's the issue; but I'm going to replace it and see what happens, because it still might be worn out front struts. Or both. Right now I'm just waiting for parts. I'll rearrange the list and put the most likely stuff on top, maybe it'll be clearer.

Comment: Camber is off by 3 degrees????? Which way, positive or negative? I had -2.5 degrees of camber in my Datsun race car and that was extreme for the street. Your suspension bushings are probably shot too. Try to replace the easy one's if you change your shocks. AND not all tires are the same.

Comment: @TimNevins you know, I don’t even remember now. That cars been sitting in my driveway for 6 months now unable to start. It’s gonna be my spring project. Once it runs smoothly again I’ll be back to tackling the suspension. I’m sure there’s a lot going on with it, from spent bushings to bent parts. But now I’ve got engine seals, rotten fuel lines, clogged egr ports, startup troubleshooting, and a probably-wise timing belt change on the todo list ahead of handling. And there’s probably at least one squirrel living in it somewhere by now. Woo fun.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like an alignment problem to me. As you stated in the comments, the bent front control arm threw your camber angle off by 3°, which will reduce your tires contact patch, thus decreasing grip making it easier to slide.

Driving with extreme camber angle on rough roads will put undue stress on the suspension components, which may have caused your toe angle (controlled by tie rods) to be effected as well.

Excessive toe angle would explain why the steering wheel is 3-4° off. It would also explain why the car seems to dart or jump when you go over bumps, as at that moment the axle is unloaded (decreasing grip), and the tire that happens to have more grip is facing a few degrees off of the direction of travel, causing the car to jump in that direction until the axle is loaded again, and the weight of the car overcomes the side load the tire is still experiencing.

Excessive toe angle would also make it easier to lose grip when stopping and starting at low speeds, as the tires are (again) experiencing load in two directions, significantly decreasing the maximum load it can handle in any one direction. It only happens at low speeds because the momentum of the vehicle has not yet cause enough forward grip to overcome the side loading of the tire.

Comment: Legends say he's still getting the vehicle repaired to this day.

Comment: Legends say the car was never repaired.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like your front tires aren't staying with the road. Without more specific information its hard to give a specific answer.

I suggest you check differential (or transaxle) or components that could affect alignment, such as shocks.

You should try to pay attention to how it behaves when both tires are being affected or only one side is being affected by road conditions at a time.
What happens when you do a U-turn from standstill? How do the tires behave?

---

**RE: u-turns are fine.**

(Make sure u-turns are good in both directions and fine with both situations of no throttle and some throttle. be safe, open lot)
If thats all good then I am going to say your differential is *probably* fine.

180k on stock shocks.. they are goners, done-zos, kaput. Without that "fixed", there is no complete fixing the rest, even if there are any other problems.

Honestly it sounds like something new shocks + alignment would fix. Bushings too probably, if you can (it'll help get rid of the tiny bumps you might be feeling now).
How is the ride height? What is it feel like on the freeway (more rapid bumps?)?

Comment: No strange behaviors during u turns.